# How can i get the 'first' item from this cards array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

So as you can see I would like to get the 'Something1', 'Something2' etc from cardInfo array, how can I iterate through in cardInfo to display every item from 'cards'?

```js
const cardInfo = [
    {
        name: "Something",
        cards: [
            {
                first: "Something1",
                second: "Something2",
                third: "Something3"
            }
        ]
    }
    
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
    let displayCards = cardInfo.map((item) => {
        return `
        <div>
          <h1>${item.name}</h1>
          <div>
            <h2>${item.cards.first}</h2>
            <h2>${item.cards.second}</h2>
            <h2>${item.cards.third}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>`;
    });
    displayCards = displayCards.join("");
    wrapper.innerHTML = displayCards;
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

Comment: `cards` is an array of one item so: `item.cards[0].first` etc.

Comment: I already tried that, but didn't work

Comment: [It does work](https://jsfiddle.net/m826axjL/).

Comment: Ye, it does, my bad :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that...

```
for (const key in cardInfo[0].cards[0]) {
  console.log(`${key}: ${cardInfo[0].cards[0][key]}`);
}
```

But I would recommend you to think about your data structure if you can still change it. If your CardInfo array grows and you have more card sets, you have to iterate again.

```
const cardInfo = [
  {
    name: 'Something',
    cards: [
      {
        first: 'Something1',
        second: 'Something2',
        third: 'Something3'
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    name: 'Other',
    cards: [
      {
        first: 'Other1',
        second: 'Other2',
        third: 'Other3'
      },
      {
        first: 'Other11',
        second: 'Other22',
        third: 'Other33'
      }
    ]
  }
];

cardInfo.forEach((set) => {
  set.cards.forEach((cardsSet) => {
    for (const key in cardsSet) {
      console.log(`${key}: ${cardsSet[key]}`);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need another `map` method to loop throw the `cards` property.

```js
const cardInfo = [
    {
        name: "Something",
        cards: [
            {
                first: "Something1",
                second: "Something2",
                third: "Something3"
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
    
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    const wrapper = document.querySelector('.wrapper');
    let displayCards = cardInfo.map((item) => {
        return `
        <div>
          <h1>${item.name}</h1>
          ${item.cards.map(({first, second, third}) => {
              return `<div>
            <h2>${first}</h2>
            <h2>${second}</h2>
            <h2>${third}</h2>
          </div>`
           }).join('')}
          
        </div>`;
    });
    displayCards = displayCards.join("");
    wrapper.innerHTML = displayCards;
});
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```